# memcached setup for max memory and expire

Tags: memcached

What is the optimum setup for memcached ? for example, how many MB memory we should assign ?
And also how long should we kept before it expires ? I tried setting memcached to expire in 1 hour. The first day it's running okay. But the next day, the server running very slow like it's running out of memory. So I delete all cache and retry with expiration down to 10 minutes.

Is there a way to tell memcached to flush if the memory used is full ? So not too make the whole website becoming very slow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached uses an LRU algorithm to remove keys when it runs out of space. You can specify how much memory memcached uses with the -m parameter. By default memcached will only use 64MB of memory.

It's possible that things are running very slowly because you may not be using the -m parameter and that would mean your cache is only 64MB meaning you aren't actually caching much.

Comment: Yes, that is it. I didn't set the memory. But if I'm using a shared memory, would my hosting has taken care of setting the memory? Let's say I have 1GB memory. How much memory could I set ?

Comment: If you have 1GB free then you can set -m 1024, but if you have other applications running on that box that use that memory then you might want to leave some space for those applications to avoid your os from swapping memory pages to disk.